# Present a UIViewController from an NSObject

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

Something happens in my datamodel, and I need to present a modal viewcontroller instantiated through the storyboard.

How can I do this? I need to present a modal VC from an NSObject, and obviously presentViewController is a UIViewController method.

What's the best way to do this?

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [(AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] storyboard];

NewMessageListenPopupVC *popupVC = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NewMessageListenPopupVC"];

[self presentViewController:popupVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

**EDIT:**

Code I am probably going to end up using:

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [(AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] storyboard];

NewMessageListenPopupVC *popupVC = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NewMessageListenPopupVC"];

UIViewController *rootVC = [[(AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController];
[rootVC presentViewController: popupVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: What is the minus one for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rYou could do this by getting the rootView controller from the window of the application and then calling presentViewController on that VC.

```
UIViewController *vc = [window rootViewController];
[vc presentViewController: yourVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: this seems like a good idea. any chance the rootVC is deallocated?

Comment: I don't think so, but there may be some edge case. Although I think the app delegate will abort if it doesn't have a rootViewController ,don't quote me on that though :P.

Comment: no window property found outside UIViewcontroller class.

Comment: MRizwan you need to get the window using UIWindow *window = [(AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window];